# BGE place object on 3D graph based on user input?

Tags: game-engine

I'm putting together a simple political graph for a friend of mine. For example, the x-axis represents economic freedom, while the y-axis represents political freedom, and the z-axis represents personal freedom. What I'm struggling with is having BGE ask the user three questions(or more in the future) for determining their political position on each axis, and then have an empty navigate there and spawn a sphere.

Here's a link to the file so far:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6_5f6jmSaHOQ0g5RWxhRDBkWG8

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the BGE is sufficient for text interaction or diagrams. It is possible, but not easy.

I suggest you look at something like presentation and/or table calculation applications.